# Set different frequencies for the two hardware PWMchannels on PI 4B

Tags: pwm

I'd like to generate two PWM signals with SAME duty cycle (50%) but DIFFERENT frequencies on raspberry pi 4B. The difference between the frequencies is within +/-80%. The two GPIOs I'll use are GPIO 18 and 19.

I also would like to have a range of frequencies too while time passing by. For example: f1 is freq of PWM channel 1 and f0 is freq of PWM channel 0.

At t = 0sec, f1=1000Hz, f0=1800Hz

t=1sec, f1 = 30Hz, f0=20Hz

t=2sec, f1 = 10Hz, f0=10Hz

...

I'm using wiringPi lib. So far I'm able to achieve variable frequency by changing the parameter "clock" using `pwmSetClock( )`. However, this function changes the PWM frequency of both channel 0 and 1. How can I set the frequencies separately for the two channels? I also thought about changing the "range" parameter using `pwmSetRange()`. However that seems changing both channels frequencies too.

I attached my code if that helps. Thank you.

```
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define N 10

int main (void) {

  if (wiringPiSetupGpio() == -1)
    exit (1) ;

  int clock_scale[N] = {4095, 2000, 1000, 500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 8}; 
  int range = 4095, duty_cycle = 2047;
  int pin_HW_PWM = 18;

  pinMode(pin_HW_PWM,PWM_OUTPUT);
  pwmSetMode(PWM_MODE_MS);
  pwmSetRange (range);
  pwmWrite(pin_HW_PWM, duty_cycle);

  while(1) {
    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)  {
      pwmSetClock(clock_scale[i]);
      printf("clock_scale[%d] = %d\n", i, clock_scale[i]);
      delay(5000);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Rpi4B's all the on board PWM pins have the same frequency. Perhaps you can consider the cheapy ICs or modules: 
(1) ICL8038CCPD DIP14 ICL8038 DIP Precision Waveform Generator/Voltage Controlled Oscillator new and original IC - AliExpress €1.65/5 pieces
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32903022445.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.c67c5eacsnzOFZ&algo_pvid=d09df81b-3b0f-4510-923e-d64607efe405&algo_expid=d09df81b-3b0f-4510-923e-d64607efe405-4&btsid=0b0a555816068050607427290e26c4&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_ / to continue ,...

Comment: (2) AD9833 Programmable Microprocessors Serial Interface Module Sine Square Wave DDS Signal Generator Module GY-9833 - AliExpress €1.37 
https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32951880152.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.c67c5eacsnzOFZ&algo_pvid=d09df81b-3b0f-4510-923e-d64607efe405&algo_expid=d09df81b-3b0f-4510-923e-d64607efe405-26&btsid=0b0a555816068050607427290e26c4&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_

Answer (score 1):

pigpio will let you set the frequencies to different values.

[Python hardware_PWM](http://pigpio/python.html#hardware_PWM)

Note that the dutycycle is set out of a million.  I.e. 500000 is 50%.

If you always want 50% duty you could use the clocks as well.  See [Python hardware_clock](http://pigpio/python.html#hardware_clock).

You can experiment from the command line by using the pigs [hp](http://pigpio/pigs.html#HP) and [hc](http://pigpio/pigs.html#HC) commands.

[C PWM](http://pigpio/cif.html#gpioHardwarePWM)

[C clock](http://pigpio/cif.html#gpioHardwareClock)